# Bash script exit on command failure (sshpass)

Tags: bash, ssh, sshpass

I need to perform an operation on a list of server, through SSH.

I am using sshpass, and that operation might fail, however it's supposed to happen a few time, and the script should still continue.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read address; do
    echo -n "$address "
    sshpass -p password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@$address 'ls /path/to/some/dir'
done < address-list
```

However, the command ran through ssh fail on the first host, and the script immediately exit.

How can I have the loop continue executing, no matter what ? Adding an exit after my command doesn't fix this, and unsetting exit on error `set +e` doesn't work either.

Comment: Your snippet seems to be missing a backtick (`)

Comment: Can you post the whole script, and let know what other options you are setting along with `set -e`

Comment: @Panki good catch, fixed it.

Comment: @Inian The script is as simple as that, basically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh` will inherit the standard input stream from the loop and read as much as possible from it, meaning it will read read the remaining lines from your `address-list` file.  Since `ssh` is reading the remaining lines from the file, the loop will only ever do a single iteration.  Technically, the script does not terminate prematurely or *fail* in any way, it just does not do what you want it to do.

To avoid this, use `ssh -n` to prevent `ssh` from reading from standard input:

```
while read address; do
    echo -n "$address "
    sshpass -p password ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "user@$address" 'ls /path/to/some/dir'
done < address-list
```

`ssh` behaves in this way so that you would be able to pass data into some program started on the remote host, but as you have discovered, in your case this will prevent your loop from functioning correctly.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation, and for the working solution.

Comment: thank you for your beautiful answer